# How do I unstub in rspec 3 without enabling the old syntax?

Tags: rspec, rspec3

I am upgrading from rspec 2 to rspec 3 and would like to use the new syntax and not enable the old syntax. But I have a few stubs that I set up in my top-level `before(:each)` block that I selectively `unstub` where I want the original implementation.

Is there some equivalent way to remove a stub when I've defined it with the new `allow` syntax?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could redifine them with

```
expect(Person).to receive(:find).and_call_original
```

which will additionaly check that the original :find method was called on person

Comment: Ah, I didn't know I could redefine it. Seems obvious now! I also see I can redefine with `allow` as well. Thanks!

Comment: You need to specify the instance of the object you want to unstub. i.e. If my `Person` instance lives in `company.boss`, then you need to call `expect(company.boss).to receive(:find).and_call_original`